# The project can be opened but can NOT be run now

Tags: android, kotlin

I download [tutorial codes from github](https://github.com/udacity/Court-Counter), and I unzip it and copy paste it to where my android studio projects are. After I update to SDK 24.0.2, the project can be opened but can NOT be run now.

Pls write a bit more words for clear instructions in steps of what do I do since I am new to android studio. A lot of time I don't understand the terms you experts use.

Can NOT run the project? the green triangle run button is grey so I can NOT run it.
[image]
I got these red messages from Event Log

```
Gradle sync failed: Unsupported method: SyncIssue.getMultiLineMessage().
The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (41 s 341 ms)
```

Comment: let me try to checkout and run this repo, will let you know

Comment: Your explanation is very clear and very good. The problem is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the repo and with only a few changes in two files was able to run the project.

update the root-level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Updated gradle version to `4.2.1` and added `google()` to resolve android dependencies.

updated my gradle distribution URL in gradle-wrapper.properties.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-bin.zip
```

Please see if the `6.7.1` is supported on your android studio or not else update to the latest as per your android studio supports, mine is the latest hence `6.7.1`

That is it, just by changing these two files I was able to run that app.

**Note:** I just did bare minimum changes just to make the app run, ideally all the dependency and everything should be up-to-date but changing all those is out of the scope of this question.

I even committed the changes in the forked version of the app code. feel free to try

https://github.com/dk19121991/Court-Counter

Answer (score 0):

Gradle is an app that Android Studio uses to manage loading the libraries of code the project is built with (among other things). But since this project you downloaded is about 5 years old, the version of Gradle in the project may not match up with what Android Studio's Android plugin can support.

Typically, the Gradle app is actually part of the project. You'll see it in the `gradle/wrapper` directory in the project. You can update the version by editing the file `gradle-wrapper.properties`, by changing the value in the `distributionUrl` line. I think you need to make the version at least 6.7.1 if you have a recently updated version of Android Studio, so change that line to look like this:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip
```

The configuration of the project is in the files named `build.gradle`. The weird thing is, that project seems to have an incorrect duplicate of `build.gradle` in the root directory of the project (it looks like the one that should go in the `app` directory). So you can delete the contents of that `build.gradle` in your root directory and replace it with what would normally be there in a new project. I just copy-pasted this out of a new project. You can paste it into that file:

```groovy
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And finally, you will want to update the `build.gradle` file that's in the `app` directory so it uses the version of Android you already have downloaded (probably SDK 30). So find these relevant lines in the file and change them:

```groovy
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

//...

        targetSdkVersion 30
```

After you've made all the above updates, press the "Sync Project with Gradle Files" button  near the right end of the toolbar to reload the project from Gradle. It will take a couple minutes because it will have to download the new Gradle version.

Comment: Gradle is not an app; it is an automatization tool. Android Studio does use it but is not Android Studio exclusive; you can potentially use it for any project; you could even install Gradle and create a Gradle project using via command line.

Comment: Please refer to the Gradle official documentation.

Comment: `Gradle is an open-source build automation tool` https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html the definition of duck doesn't explicitly say it is not an airplane yet both can fly.

Comment: Being a "build automation tool" doesn't contradict its status as an independently runnable application, not part of an OS.